# Solve the initial value problem: $\frac{dx}{dt}=2t \sin x$; $x(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the initial value problem: $\frac{dx}{dt}=2t \sin x$; $x(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}$
I am almost done. But I cannot seem to solve the equation for x(t) in terms of t. 
This is what I got:
$$
\frac{dx}{\sin x}=2tdt\\
\csc x =2tdt\\
-\ln|\csc x+\cot x|=t^2+C\\
\ln \frac{1}{|\csc x+\cot x|}=t^2+C\\
\frac{1}{\csc x+\cot x}=\pm e^Ce^{t^2}
$$

So now I need to know what x(t) is. How do get the expression for x(t)?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{dt}&=2t \sin x\\
\frac{dx}{\sin x}&=2t \ dt\\
\csc x \ dx&= 2t \ dt\\
-\log(\csc x + \cot x)&=t^2+C_1\\
\log((\frac{1+\cos x}{\sin x})^{-1})&=t^2+C_1\\
\log (\tan\frac{x}{2})&=t^2+C_1\\
\tan{\frac{x}{2}}&=Ce^{t^2}\\
x(t)&=2\arctan(Ce^{t^2})
\end{align*}

For the initial condition:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\pi}{2}&= 2\arctan(Ce^{0})\\
\tan( \frac{\pi}{4}) &=C\\
C&=1
\end{align*}

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{dx}{\sin x} = 2tdt$

Comment: We shouldn't be answering questions which do not stand up to community standards. OP should fix it before we answer.

Comment: As the OP didn't ask the question probably, now it seems that your answer did not answer the question.